# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError while hosted on azure

Tags: java, azure-web-app-service

I read the other post like this, and though they did make me go check certain things none actually help me come up with a fix...

My jre is below

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

My application runs fine in my IDE, but I get this error when my site is hosted live on Azure

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Servlets/IMDbServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class Servlets.IMDbServlet)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2576)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: This means the code was compiled for java 8 but the jre that's running it does not support java 8 code

Answer (score 1):

Check what version of java is being used on your azure deployment.
There must be a difference between the one you are using and the one being used on your azure deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Java version must be same or higher than Java byte-code (compile time) version.
*major.minor version 52.0* refers to Java 8. So Java runtime environment of your Azure server should be older than Java 8.
As a fix you can check your Azure Java version and compile the sources with same Java version.